# Bim 360 pushpin extension used in forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

Is it possible to customize the pushpins icons in forge viewer?
here my sample code which is loading "quality-issues" in the viewer.

```
 _viewer3D.loadExtension('Autodesk.BIM360.Extension.PushPin', extensionOptions)
.then((pushPinExtension) => {
  PushPinExtensionHandle = pushPinExtension;
  //remove last items collection
  pushPinExtension.removeAllItems();
  pushPinExtension.showAll();

  //get out the data of this pushpin
  var labelData = $('#labelPushpinParam').text();
  var ItemsFromBIM360API = JSON.parse(labelData);
  renderIssues(ItemsFromBIM360API, pushPinExtension);
});
```

And renderIssue() function will render the pushpins in viewer.

```
function renderIssues(issues, pushPinExtension) {` issues.forEach(issueData => {
pushPinExtension.createItem({
  type: issueData.type,
  id: issueData.id,
  label: issueData.title,
  status: issueData.type + '-' + issueData.status,
  position: issueData.location,
  objectId: issueData.object_id,
  viewerState: issueData.viewerState
});});`}
```

[How pushpins are looking once rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PszJd.png)

I want to change that pushpin circle into some other icon. How can we do this?

Comment: You could inspect the page and hover over the pushpin to see if there is a css class associated with it. If so you might be able to override it !

Comment: Thank you so much Samuel, you saved my life.

Comment: Cool beans, did this answer your question ?